# Trying to show that a certain space is complete with complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I had the following task in my functionalanalysis class:

Let $D:=\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\rbrace $ and let $H^2(D)$ be the set of analytic functions  $f:D\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with $\int_D|f(x+iy)|^2dxdy< \infty$. Show that $H^2(D)$ with the innerproduct:

$$(f,g):=\int_D\overline{f(x+iy)}g(x+iy)dxdy$$

is a Hilbertspace.

---

All there is to do is to show that our space is complete. I liked to tackle the hole task with thinking about complex analysis and eventhough my professor told me his solution was something different and I am kind of out of the box. I really enjoyed the journey with my idea. But there is one step im not 100 percent sure off, could someone please give me the missing argument I am not seeing.

My proof:

---

To show a normed Space $H^2(D)$ is complete is equivalent to show that the following holds:

$$\sum^\infty_n ||f_n||<\infty \Longrightarrow \sum^\infty_n f_n = f$$

with $f \in H^2(D)$. (proved in some exercises before, some weeks ago)

So let now

$$\sum^\infty_n ||f_n||=\sum^\infty_n\left(\int_D|f_n(x+iy)|^2dxdy\right)^{1/2}<\infty $$

First note that since we have a finite measure space it follows from hölders inequality that:

$$\sum^\infty_n\int_D |f_n(x+iy)|dxdy\le\text{Vol}(D)^{1/2}\sum^\infty_n\left(\int_D|f_n(x+iy)|^2dxdy\right)^{1/2}<\infty  $$

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $D$, so continouity gives us an $a \in K$ such that:
$\forall z \in K : |f_n(z)|\le|f_n(a)|$

Since $f_n$ is holomorph we know for sufficently small $R>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$:

$$ |f_n(a)|\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{\partial B_R(a)}\frac{|f_n(z)|}{R}dz=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2\pi\varepsilon}\int^\varepsilon_0\oint_{\partial B_R(a)}\frac{|f_n(z)|}{R}dzdr\le \int_D |f_n(x+iy)|dxdy} $$

We can now use the Weierstraß-Criterion to conclude the series $\sum^\infty_n f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on  any compact $K$. Which means we can exchange limits and use Moreras Theorem:

$$\oint_{\partial\Delta} \sum^\infty_n f_n(z) dz = \sum^\infty_n \oint_{\partial\Delta} f_n(z) dz =0$$

for any triangle in the inner of the compactum. Since this works for any triangle and any compactum, the series is indeed holomorphic. The Identity Theorem states, that our series indeed converges on whole $D$ against the same limit and the function is holomorph. Since $L^2(D)$ is complete, our limit is also in $L^2$.
And finally we are done.

---

Care, the red colored part could be absolute nonsense, but ive got the feeling it might work with certain options. Could someone please give me some options or method to make this inequality work, or something as usefull. Or just tell me that this will never work..

Thank you very much

Comment: A quick remark: $a$ may depend on $n$; you can't guarantee that the same point works for the whole sequence. For the red part, the idea is mostly correct I think, but notation makes it nonsense-looking: Write $z\in \partial B_R(a)$ as $z=a+R\zeta$ where $\zeta\in \partial B_1(0)$ so that the line-integration is happening in $\zeta$, and then your second integration (which should be from $0$ to $R$) happening in $r$ combine to make a full integral over $B_R(a)$.

Comment: ahh I see, but that shouldnt stop the argument I think? (with the dependency)

Comment: Or better: My idea of the proof should be adjustable?

Comment: It doesn't really affect anything: Just treat $a$ as a generic point. Then what you'd be showing is that for all $a\in B_s(0)$ with $s<1$, we have $|f_n(a)|\leq C_s \| f_n\|$.